# Prevent prompt when `apt install -y iptables persistent` on Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, debian, iptables

I'm making a script of auto-starting server.

when I exec following command, I get blue screen prompt.
What the name of the scereen?

```bash
apt install -y iptables-persistent
```

The goal what I wanna do is one of following

- prevent this prompt to raise
- send command (ENTER) to this prompt

Of course, 2-times manual ENTER solve this problem, but I want to automate this step.

what I tried:

- `apt install -y iptables-persistent > /dev/null`
- `apt install -y iptables-persistent $ echo "\n"`
- `expect -c "spawn apt install -y iptables-persistent expect\"\(.*\)\" send --\"\n\""`

[ENVIRONMENT]

- Debian 9
- Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this command to fully automate the installation

```
echo iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v4 boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections
echo iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v6 boolean true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get -y install iptables-persistent
```

Comment: what if `iptables-persistent` is a dependency of another package? the preinst script is executed after installing dependecies, so it can not be added to that script.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this way to fully automate the installation:

```bash
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v4 boolean true"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v6 boolean true"

sudo apt install -y iptables-persistent
```

Another way is:

```bash
sudo debconf-set-selections <<EOF
iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v4 boolean true
iptables-persistent iptables-persistent/autosave_v6 boolean true
EOF

sudo apt install -y iptables-persistent
```

Comment: This is vaguely somewhat more elegant than the accepted answer, but the differences are quite minor. Perhaps at least explain why you think this should be preferred?

Comment: All methods are the same and have no difference. I just wanted to say other methods.

Comment: A single invocation of `debconf-set-selections` is preferable because you generally want to minimize the number of external processes. Running two instead of one is not a big deal, but a bit of an unpleasant smell when the alternative is also more legible.